# Changing space in the supreme, surjectivity argument

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis

Let $\Omega$ an open subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$ with continuous boundary and $f:X\to L_0^2(\Omega)$ a surjective function, with $X$ another Hilbert space and $\displaystyle L_0^2(\Omega):=\left\{u\in L^2(\Omega):\int_\Omega u=0\right\}$. We know that

$$||u||_{L^2(\Omega)}=\sup_{v\in L_0^2(\Omega)\setminus 0}\dfrac{\langle u,v\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}}{||v||_{L^2(\Omega)}}$$

By the surjectivity of $f$, there exists $\phi\in X$ such that $f(\phi)=v$. Furthermore, suppose that $||\phi||_X\leq C||v||_{0,\Omega}$ with $C>0$.

**Is it true that**

$$||u||_{L^2(\Omega)}=\sup_{v\in L_0^2(\Omega)\setminus 0}\dfrac{\langle u,v\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}}{||v||_{L^2(\Omega)}}\leq C\sup_{\phi\in X\setminus 0}\dfrac{\langle u,f(\phi)\rangle_{L_0^2(\Omega)}}{||\phi||_X}$$

**?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, $f$ is also one-to-one, due to the fact that
$$
\|\varphi\|_X\le C\,\|v\|_{L^2(\Omega)}=C\,\|f(\varphi)\|_{L^2(\Omega)},\tag{1}
$$
and since thus
\begin{align}
\|u\|_{L^2_0(\Omega)}=\sup_{v\in L_0^2(\Omega)\setminus 0}\dfrac{\langle u,v\rangle_{L^2(\Omega)}}{\|v\|_{L^2_0(\Omega)}}=
\sup_{\varphi\in X\setminus 0}\dfrac{\langle u,f(\varphi)\rangle_{L_0^2(\Omega)}}{\|f(\varphi)\|_{L^2_0(\Omega)}}.
\end{align}
But if $\varphi\ne 0$, then \tag{1} implies that
$$
\dfrac{\langle u,f(\varphi)\rangle_{L_0^2(\Omega)}}{\|f(\varphi)\|_{L^2_0(\Omega)}} 
\le C\dfrac{\langle u,f(\varphi)\rangle_{L_0^2(\Omega)}}{\|\varphi\|_X}
$$
Hence
$$
\sup_{\varphi\in X\setminus 0}\dfrac{\langle u,f(\varphi)\rangle_{L_0^2(\Omega)}}
{\|f(\varphi)\|_{L^2_0(\Omega)}} \le\sup_{\varphi\in X\setminus 0}
C\dfrac{\langle u,f(\varphi)\rangle_{L_0^2(\Omega)}}{\|\varphi\|_X}.
$$

Comment: thanks for your answer! =)